# ClassNotFoundException,Missing ServletContainerAdaptor

Tags: web-services, rest, servlets

I am creating one REstfulwebservices project. When ever I am going to run this 
    project   then I am getting this error. ClassNot FoundException...ServletAdaptor
    problem.

```
 SEVERE: Servlet /XybuyProject threw load() exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   
 com.sun.jersey.server.spi.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor
at 

 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:996)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4834)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5155)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is Web.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns    
   /javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <display-name>FirstProject</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index2.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
com.sun.jersey.server.spi.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersy.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>com.xybuy.webservice</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/REST/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

can you tel me what is the problem behind it.....

Comment: can you check the particular class(the jar) is available in the classpath?...Classnot found exception occurs only,if the server couldnt find the particuular class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace, you seem to be using Tomcat, which is a barebones JSP/Servlet container and not a full fledged Java EE container. Jersey is a JAX-RS implementation which is usually already bundled in fullfledged Java EE application servers such as Glassfish. Perhaps you were reading a Jersey book/tutorial or downloading a sample targeted on Glassfish or another Java EE container and thus it will be assumed that you don't need to install it separately.

However, on Tomcat, Jersey is thus not bundled and you will get `ClassNotFoundException`s on Jersey classes when declaring them in `web.xml`. You need to [download](http://jersey.java.net/) the Jersey JAR file(s) separately and drop them in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp.

Comment: I have already added jersey jar file inside the WEB-INF/lib folder.Still have same problem.....

Comment: Which JARs exactly have you placed in there? The mentioned class is part of `jersey-server.jar`. You can download all the three necessary JARs on Jersey download page.